# SSID evaluation within the 802.11 protocol

Tags: computer-networks

Inspired by a [question on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1595348), I was reading up on the 802.11 protocol. This made me wonder if the SSID is actively used outside the authentication and association process. I know that it can be included in beacon frames which will get evaluated after a connection between AP and client has been established. But since within beacon frames the SSID value is optional, it makes me think it does not get evaluated.

So my question is, will the SSID usually be evaluated during a connection between AP and client **after** the authentication and association process? Is this a required within the 802.11 protocol or is this up to the implementation?

I hope computer science is the right site to ask this question since I don't feel it belongs on Network Engineering because it's too theoretical.